# Logging jboss without adjusting log4j.xml

Tags: jboss, log4j, jmx

We're running servers with JBoss on them and log4j for errors. I've been asked to come up with a way to log things like freememory and active thread group count so that we can monitor these without having to go through the jboss console. However, I've been told that it'd be preferred if I could do this without having to make any changes to the existing servers. My original thought was to change the log4j.xml to persist the relevant data to a database to parse out and display later, however now I really don't know.
Is there any other way, without installing a 3rd party app, to automatically grab information from a jboss server and persist it? Or should I just keep fighting to be allowed to modify the log4j xml?
Also, is this even possible? I've looked all over for examples but nowhere has specifically stated that you can use log4j to also log system stats.

Answer (score 0):

Hunter;

Assuming there are no network impediments and JMX remoting has not been disabled in any way, you can remotely monitor these values using the JMX API. Here's some Groovy code to do this, but you can translate this to Java easilly.

```
import javax.management.*;
import javax.naming.*;
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
p.put("jnp.disableDiscovery", "true");
ctx = new InitialContext(p);
contexts.put(url, ctx);
mbeanServer = ctx.lookup("/jmx/rmi/RMIAdaptor");
// Lookups here
```

Put **/client/jbossall-client.jar** in your classpath.

Now just scroll through JMXConsole (on a Dev server if you must) and pick the attributes and ObjectName you want to collect. For example, extending the example above, to get FreeMemory (groovy again):

```
import javax.management.*;
def objectName = new ObjectName("jboss.system:type=ServerInfo");
def freeMem = mbeanServer.getAttribute(objectName, "FreeMemory");
```

In your JMXConsole, that maps to this MBean:

[image]

and to this attribute in that MBean:

[image]

So if you set up a scheduler to collect this data from time to time, you can write it to a DB, put it in an email or whatever.

Make sense ?

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for your very in depth and helpful answer, Nicholas! While some of the stuff in the first bit of Groovy code is pretty foreign to me at first look, it all makes sense from a logic viewpoint and I'm sure I can figure out the equivalent in java. My only question right now is what would the value of url be in the line p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);"? the url for the jmx-console?

Comment: By default, it will be host:1099